# Layout footer text in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I need to display a TextView at the bottom of a ScrollView, such that:

- If the height of the content of the ScrollView is less than the height of the ScrollView, the text should be at the bottom of the ScrollView

  ```
  +============+
  |  content   |
  |            |
  +------------+
  |   w/space  |
  |            |
  +------------+
  | footer txt |
  +============+
  ```
- If the height of the content of the ScrollView is greater than the height of the ScrollView, then the text should directly follow the content.

  ```
  +============+
  |  content   |
  |            |
  |            |
  |  content   |
  |            |
  |            |
  |  content   |
  +============+
  :            : \  
  :  content   :  bottom edge of device
  :------------:
  : footer txt :
  +------------+
  ```

I have a programmatic solution, but it's fiddly & I keep finding corner cases where I need to recalculate & request layout.

Can I achieve this layout using XML only?

Comment: This looks tough to solve purely with XML. I'd probably use a FrameLayout to overlay the footer text when the content isn't long enough, then hide it and display a copy of the footer text that is within the ScrollView when the content is longer than the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as creating another layout under the scroll view layout to hold all the content, and then sticking the footer text under the content layout.

here's the solution in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- PUT YOUR CONTENT IN THIS LAYOUT -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footerText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="footer text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If all your content is uniform, then your best bet actually is using a ListView and setting the TextView footer programmatically as such:

```
listView.addFooterView(yourTextView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon a blog post by Romain Guy from 2010 that talks about this exact problem and how to solve it.

http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

The ScrollView should have the property `android:fillViewport="true"` and the view within the ScrollView's child view that is to expand to fill the space should be the only one with a specified `layout_weight`.

I've just tested this approach and it works as intended.